# PHPSpreadsheet generates invalid file with charts

Tags: excel, php-7, phpspreadsheet

I am migrating the existing/working app from `PHPExcel` (`phpoffice/phpexcel: 1.8.0`) to `PHPSpreadsheet` and I have hit an issue when generating Excel file containing **one or more charts**.

Without any `addChart` calls, the generated file is valid, but as soon as I add a chart, the resulting file becomes invalid. Excel does attempt to recover the data, which succeeds but without a chart.

Excel recovery tool shows:

```
Excel completed file level validation and repair. 
Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)
```

Current using: PHP 7.1 and `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet: "1.10.1"`

My code is very similar to Example for PieChart, which I am attempting to add.

Part of the code which generates PieChart:

- `$ageCounterRowIndex` has value 6
- `$expectedPointCount` has value 4
- My data tick values are located in `D3:D6`
- My values are located in `E3:E6`

```
$dataSeriesLabels = [];

$xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, "$quotedSheetTitle\$D\$3:\$D\$$ageCounterRowIndex", $expectedPointCount)
];

$dataSeriesValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, "$quotedSheetTitle\$E\$3:\$E\$$ageCounterRowIndex", $expectedPointCount),
];

$dataSeries = new DataSeries(
    DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,
    NULL, 
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1), 
    $dataSeriesLabels, 
    $xAxisTickValues, 
    $dataSeriesValues 
);

$pieLayout = new Layout();
$pieLayout->setShowVal(TRUE)->setShowPercent(TRUE);

$plotArea = new PlotArea($pieLayout, [ $dataSeries ]);
$legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, FALSE);

$chart = new Chart(
    'piechart_' . ($sheetIndex - 1), 
    null,
    $legend, 
    $plotArea, 
    true, 
    0, 
    NULL, 
    NULL 
);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('G2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('L15');
$sheet->addChart($chart);
```

Answer (score 8):

Changing the `displayBlanksAs` parameter in the New Chart call from `0` to `'gap'` solved this issue for me.

I found this bug report about it on the [PhpSpreadsheet repository](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1337)

```
$chart = new Chart(
    'piechart_' . ($sheetIndex - 1), 
    null,
    $legend, 
    $plotArea, 
    true, 
    0, 
    NULL, 
    NULL 
);
```

becomes

```
$chart = new Chart(
    'piechart_' . ($sheetIndex - 1), 
    null,
    $legend, 
    $plotArea, 
    true, 
    'gap', 
    NULL, 
    NULL 
);
```

Comment: Ouuh... definitely worth trying this out... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had all developed, but still having this issue, so... thanks!

Comment: I was able to fix a similar issue by using 'zero' in place of 0 or 'gap'.

Comment: wow. struggled for a few hours before I saw this. Thank you so much!